# Star pyramid program in c

Tags: c

I have output in image, but code is not proper
i want code for the given output

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   int i, space, rows, k = 0;
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &rows);
   for (i = 1; i <= rows; ++i, k = 0) {
      for (space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space) {
         printf("  ");
      }
      while (k != 2 * i - 1) {
         printf("* ");
         ++k;
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the image is what you want, or what you currently get?

Comment: Above code is code print star pyramid

Comment: Why did you write it down on a piece of paper and then take a picture?  Please post this as text so people can help you more easily.

Comment: Okay, from next time I will not do like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was a little difficult to understand, I'm assuming you're asking how to get the output as described in the image. This code does that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int rows;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for (int i=0; i<rows; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<rows*2-1; ++j) {
            if (j <= i || j >= rows*2-2-i) {
                printf("* ");
            } else {
                printf("  ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the output that is in the photo, but i don't have the code for it, the above code is print star pyramid.